# JSON cannot unmarshal object into GO value of type string

Tags: javascript, html, go

Writing Golang app using `github.com/zserge/lorca` package.
This binds golang funcs to Javascript.
I have HTML with text input and submit button which should pass the text input as an arg into the Javascript binding. It looks as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="MACADD" style="height:20px; width:210px">
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="JSBINDFUNC(MACADD)">
```

The `JSBINDFUNC` takes golang type `string` for input. 
When I hit submit, it should be passing the text entered for `MACADD` as an arg into the `JSBINDFUNC` func.

However, I'm coming back with the err

```
exception":{"type":"string","value":"json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type string"}
```

Needing this `object` to become golang `string`.

More complete snip:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/url"

    "github.com/zserge/lorca"
)

func main() {
    ui, err := lorca.New("data:text/html,"+url.PathEscape(`
        <html>
                <form action="/action_page.php">
                    MAC Address:<br>
                    <input type="text" name="MACADD" style="height:20px; width:210px">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="JSBINDFUNC(MACADD)">
                </form> 
            </body>
        </html>
        `), "", 480, 320)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    //ui.Bind implemented @ https://github.com/zserge/lorca/blob/master/ui.go#L110
    ui.Bind("JSBINDFUNC", func(MAC string) {
        fmt.Println(MAC)
        return
    })
    defer ui.Close()
    <-ui.Done()
}
```

Comment: You need to post your go-code snippet.  Not being familiar with this pkg, I would suspect one marshals form data into a struct - since forms have many fields - and marshaling into a single string will not work.

Comment: @colminator just updated, you should be able to copy/paste, `go build` and get the exact error. Make sure you've got Chrome installed.

Comment: should html be something like `MACADD.value` ?

Comment: @atayenel GENIUS. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with your javascript. Update your onclick attribute like so:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="JSBINDFUNC(MACADD.value)">
```

Comment: I just changed `JSBINDFUNC(MACADD)` to `JSBINDFUNC(MACADD.value)` per @atayenel. This works.

Comment: I justed edited the answer to reflect @atayenel shorter suggestion

Comment: I like lorca. I'm glad it was html problem and not a lorca problem :)